# why does scanf only return the number of input that it has succesfully read?

Tags: c, io

I'm Currently Learning a C program and I have a simple program to read an Integer Input, the code was shown below:

```
int main() 
{ 
    int x; 
    printf("%d",scanf("%d",&x));  
    /* Suppose that input value given  
        for above scanf is 45 */
    return 1; 
}
```

The Ouput was `1`.

And When I tried this code:

```
int main() 
{ 
    int x, z;
    printf("Enter The Value: ");
    int y = scanf("%d %d",&x, &z);
    printf("The value is %d", y);  
    /* Suppose that input value given  
        for above scanf is 20 789 */
    return 1; 
}
```

The Ouput was `2`.

So here is my question, why does `scanf` only return the `number of input` instead the `value` by the user input? Can someone explain how does it work?

Comment: So you can tell if it was successful and if not, how badly it failed.

Comment: The values that the user input are put in the variables `x` and `z`. Why would you need it returned as well? And if there are multiple inputs, which one would be returned? What if the value being input isn't an integer?

Comment: I'm not sure but in case it failed, it doesn't read that value. I tried to use an input which are not an integer, except for string and char it still givet the number of input read.

Comment: and sorry actually it doesn't really need to returned it as well, but I'm curious with this and hope to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` can process more than one input -- in your second example, it's reading two inputs into `x` and `z`. And the inputs can be many different types, but the return value of a function has to be specified as a particular type, in this case `int`.

Since `scanf()` puts the user inputs into the variables specified in the arguments, there's no need to return it as the function value as well.

Returning the number of inputs allows you to tell how successful it was. If you have two `%d` in the format string, but it returns only `1`, it means that the second input didn't look like an integer. Only `x` will be filled in, `z` will not be updated. So you should check whether the return value is equal to the number of inputs you were trying to parse, and report a problem if they don't match.

Comment: I see that's true, when input a string after the first input, the output is `1`. but why when the first input is a `char` and second input is `Integer` the output is `0`. the second input was an integer though?

Comment: It processes inputs in order. Once it fails to match, it stops.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial, it should explain this in detail.

Comment: certainly I need a tutorial, so I tried to googling it but it seems I can't get the correct keyword. Thanks and appreciate for your help.

Comment: `c scanf tutorial` Although most of these only show the simplest stuff, they don't go into much detail.

Comment: I agree with that, Learning and practice will help instead. and btw so sorry it doesn's really need to return its value, it is just i'm curious about it.

Comment: A good C textbook should do better than these limited tutorial pages.